# Apex - Server Connection not accepted

Tags: oracle-apex

so I currently have to work with Apex for the first time. My job is to make a Page that displays data previously sent by E-Mail.

I now have a "Interactive Report" set up and theoretically only have to add some SQL-Query code to get the data.

I dicided to use the "Local Database" as source and "SQL-Query" as Type. The code I wrote is `select * from lu34pisi14vm.org`.

But when I use this code the error message `connection description for remote database not found` pops up.

Does someone know why and how to fix this?

Kind regards
Elias

Comment: What does lu34pisi14vm.org. refer to ?

Comment: It is the servername with the domain,

Comment: That is not how apex works. Apex runs **in the database** so whenever you try to select something - just select from the table. You're already in the database, no need to try to establish a connection (btw, to do "select from " you first need a connection, it's not possible to do "select from <here is my connection>").
What you are trying to do assumes that the emails that are being sent are stored in a table in your database. Is that the case ? What table are they in ?

Comment: No, only the data is stored in the database, we just get an E-Mail with the data in it, written in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to use

- location: local database (as you did)
- type: **table / view** (instead of SQL Query)
- table owner: usually set to "parsing schema"
- table name: select it from list of values - doing so, you can't *miss*

Because, error you got suggests that you're using a database link which is invalid.

Comment: Yes, this works, but I can not find the data that I need in those tables, do I need to add my data extra, and if so, can i do it in Apex?

Comment: In Apex, a workspace is "mapped" to certain database schema. If schema - that contains table (and data) you're interested in - isn't mapped to your workspace, you can't see it in the list. You can use a database link, but syntax looks different from what you posted; should be something like `select * from lu34pisi14vm@org` (where ORG represents database link name). So, what is `lu34pisi14vm.org` you used in your query, exactly? Does that SELECT return anything when you run it in Apex SQL Workspace?

Comment: No, it returns the same error.

Comment: Then you have to fix it first.

Comment: Do you know "how" to fix it? Or do you have an Idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I told you - it looks as if **database link** is invalid (and the way you're using it is strange). I don't have access to your database so I can't look at it myself. If you didn't create that database link, find the one who did.

Comment: So if the link is not even created, how would I do that? Do i need access to the Server?

Comment: You'd use CREATE DATABASE LINK command. Access to *which* server? Database server? We (developers) have access to certain schema. The best option is - as I said - if workspace is mapped to that schema, and schema contains data you're working with. If data resides in another database, you have to create a database link. Developers may, or may not do that - depending on privileges DBA granted. If you can't do it yourself, ask your DBA.

Comment: Yes, if I need access to the server with the data. And how do I map a workspace to a schema? And I have admin rights for the Apex application and I access to the admin account on the server.

Comment: Mapping is done during workspace creation. If you didn't do it then, connect to Apex as ADMIN user and do it now. If you're also admin on the database server, no problem in creating a database link either. So, all prerequisites are met, you just have to *do it*.

Comment: I know, but here is the problem that I am to stupid to do so. I get no clue out of any research I do and I am not smart enough to figure it out on my own...

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid, your problem exceeds Stack Overflow purpose. We do discuss problems people have, but it seems that your problem is just too broad. Did you do any kind of Oracle training? SQL? Apex? Anything? If not, consider taking a course.

Comment: I know the basics of SQL and asked some colleagues for help with Apex, but noone know an answer. If i can´t find anything else on the Internet, I think a small training might be helpfull...

Comment: I know created a table and added the data to it by a file, that I created by Excel. But thanks for the help. Maybe someone of my colleagues can figure this out...