# Apex - Create DB link

Tags: sql, database, oracle-apex, apex

so, I have to make an Application Page with Oracle Apex. It is relatively simple, I only need one table. I tried to connect to it by SQL, but here comes the problem. There is no DB-Link existing.

How do I create a database link. I have Admin rights for Apex and have access to the admin account on the database server, from which I would need the data. Previously the data would be sended by E-Mail to us.

The sending Mailadress is *adminname@servername.domain.net*, that way I know on which server the database is located

I sadly do not know how the Mail Protocoll works, cause this was created before I started there.
I also do not know where on the server the database is located, all I know is that it is somewhere on the server.

Kind regards
Elias

Comment: Very similar to your previous question one hour ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71938243/apex-server-connection-not-accepted.

Comment: Sorry, that the question sounds so rude, but i can not add a simple"Hi," to the beginning

Comment: @jarlh Yes, but i sadly don´t get anny helpful answers and comments anymore, just that i should "fix" it.

Comment: How is this question improved, to get better answers?

Comment: I hope so, cause i know now why the error acourd and can now ask how to fix the specific problem.

Comment: You're asking the wrong questions. I'm afraid you also have a couple of wrong assumptions... Apex is a development platform on top of an oracle database. You want to query outgoing emails. Afaik, **outgoing smtp emails are not stored in a database**. An email domain ... is **not** a database. So there is nothing to connect your apex application to... Do some research on how smtp emails work and if it is at all possible to satisfy your request.

Comment: No, the data is stored in a database on the server, but the servername is in the E-Mail adress. This is only useful for knowing from which server the data is send. somewhere on the Server is the database with the data.

Comment: You're pretty much on your own. It's not possible to just connect to a database if you don't know the connection string and the credentials. You need those before you can create that db link.

Comment: OK, thanks, guess I can´t do anything then...

Comment: I know created a table and added the data to it by a file, that I created by Excel. But thanks for the help.